# How does automatic bouties work after deadline?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

I read the guide for bounties and it is stated that after 24 hours of deadline to the bounty, if the answer is not selected, it will be awarded automatically. But there was no explanation of how it will be done.

I read other expired bounty questions but didn't find how it is taken care of?

So, how is it going to be given? Manual Check for best answer as per moderators or automatic assignment over most upvote, most recent?

Answer (score 0):

It's right there in the answer of the Bounties info [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/284336)... perhaps that's not where you're looking. I'll post it here but this will likely get closed as a dupe of this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

The **bold** section is the part you want to see. :)

> ### What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?
>
> ### What is automatic awarding?
>
> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
>
> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period, that answer is awarded the bounty (provided that the answer was posted during the bounty period). Answers accepted before the bounty period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, **if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring [answer] is awarded half the bounty amount.** The criteria for an answer to be eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

Comment: Thanks, i voted this for duplicate